# nodejs cluster - socket.io-emitter send data to specific client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cluster-computing, socket.io-redis

I am building nodejs - socket.io application with nodejs cluster.

socket.io-redis

```
var ioredis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(ioredis({ host: config.redisIp, port: config.redisPort }));
```

socket.io-emitter

```
var io = require('socket.io-emitter')({ host: settings.redisIp, port: settings.redisPort });
io.emit('test', 'test');
```

its working but, sending to all connected sockets. How can i select specific client without using room types. like,

```
io.to({_id: user._id}).emit('test', 'test'); //its not work. socket._id synchronized on connect event.
```

any idea for select specific client on socket.io cluster app ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var io = require('socket.io-emitter')({ host: settings.redisIp, port: settings.redisPort });
io.to(socketId).emit('test', 'test');
```